# Как сделать дамп всего адресного пространства процесса?

Tags: winapi, память

Добрый день! Подскажите общий алгоритм дампа **всего** адресного пространства процесса, **всей** памяти, принадлежащей процессу? Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с Windows 7 есть спец. библиотека **DbgHelp.dll** (Работает и на более ранних версиях, можно взять в Windows SDK), В ней есть функция [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), которая позволяет сделать дамп процесса. Если посмотреть на возможные [типы дампов](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680519(v=vs.85).aspx), которые она делает, думаю как раз то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, ребят, действительно то, что нужно:) А как получить в самой программе доступ к памяти процесса (для поиска определённого значения)? Это можно сделать, просмотрев кучи через GetProcessHeaps() (код выполняется из DLL, которую инжектили в процесс)?

Answer (score 4):

Все 4 Гб виртуальной памяти, я полагаю, Вам всё-таки не нужны. Достаточно снять дамп закоммиченной памяти и стека.

Для этого используются функции из специально библиотеки от Microsoft [DbgHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679309(v=vs.85).aspx).

Чтобы снять дамп памяти, смотрите в сторону [Minidump Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680369(v=vs.85).aspx).

Чтобы погулять по стеку используйте [::StackWalk64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650(v=vs.85).aspx).